# combine or iterate dplyr rows on specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

I have a dataset that contains chat conversations between 2 parties. I would like to combine the dataset to row by row conversation between Person 1 and Person 2.

Sometimes people will type in multiple sentences and these will appear as multiple records within the dataframe.

This is the pseudo code that i am trying to figure out.

- line_text to be combined
- timestamp to be updated with the latest time
- if the line_by show that the same person typed in multiple lines and
  sent through their chat
- since there are multiple id's in this dataset signifying each
  conversation record between person 1 and person 2, i would like the
  loop to be run by each unique id.

This is that the dataframe looks like now:

```
id    timestamp line_by line_text
1234    02:54.3 Person1 Text Line 1
1234    03:23.8 Person2 Text Line 2
1234    03:47.0 Person2 Text Line 3
1234    04:46.8 Person1 Text Line 4
1234    05:46.2 Person1 Text Line 5
9876    06:44.5 Person2 Text Line 6
9876    07:27.6 Person1 Text Line 7
9876    08:17.5 Person2 Text Line 8
9876    10:20.3 Person2 Text Line 9
```

I would like to see the data to be changed to the following:

```
id    timestamp line_by line_text
1234    02:54.3 Person1 Text Line 1
1234    03:47.0 Person2 Text Line 2Text Line 3
1234    05:46.2 Person1 Text Line 4Text Line 5
9876    06:44.5 Person2 Text Line 6
9876    07:27.6 Person1 Text Line 7
9876    10:20.3 Person2 Text Line 8Text Line 9
```

Disclosure: I have asked the same question but for pandas in python. This is where I am getting stuck at both R and [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334930/combine-or-iterate-pandas-rows-on-specific-columns#).

Comment: It looks like in the second data frame (the one you want), the time stamp is not correct for Text Line 2 for id 1234 Person 2 (should be 03:23.8, but is showing as 03:47.0). I'm not sure I understand the pattern you're looking for here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
  group_by(id, grp = rleid(line_by)) %>%
  summarise(timestamp = last(timestamp),
            line_by = unique(line_by), line_text = paste(line_text, collapse=", ")) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

The trick is to group by `rleid(...)` in addition to the `id`

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     # id timestamp line_by            line_text
  # <int>     <chr>   <chr>                <chr>
# 1  1234   02:54.3 Person1            TextLine1
# 2  1234   03:47.0 Person2 TextLine2, TextLine3
# 3  1234   05:46.2 Person1 TextLine4, TextLine5
# 4  9876   06:44.5 Person2            TextLine6
# 5  9876   07:27.6 Person1            TextLine7
# 6  9876   10:20.3 Person2 TextLine8, TextLine9
```

Comment: I really wish `dplyr` had its own version of `rleid`, I started trying to answer this question but then got distracted trying to figure out how to write one!

Comment: Thank you. This does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A variation using only `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id,line_by,grp = cumsum(line_by !=lag(line_by,1,""))) %>%
  summarise(timestamp = last(timestamp),line_text = paste(line_text,collapse="")) %>%
  select(-grp)
```